# How to pass list of Java objects to a stored procedure from JPA

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

We have a requirement in which we have to call a stored procedure from `JPA (eclipselink)` which takes list of oracle object as input.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Within strict standards JPA, I don't think so.  With Eclipselink there is a way, have a look at http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/solutions/oracledb002.htm#CHDDCIEC.  With Hibernate also seems to be a way http://dinukaroshan.blogspot.be/2009/08/hibernate-and-oracle-user-defined-types.html

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. But the link tells about getting a Oracle record defined as OUT parameter in the java layer . However I need to pass a List of records to the Stored procedure as IN parameter.

Answer (score 0):

EclipseLink does provide a way to pass Java Object to Stored Procedures.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/PLSQLStoredFunction

and have a look at this as well

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Stored_Procedures_in_JPA_2.0

Comment: very hard to find example with a LIST of objects. Not object alone.